# Top of page gets stuck for a while when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, drupal-7, frontend

**Latest Update**: Could find the exact JS file dealing with the sticky header.Attached the same.

I have recently started maintaining a website that already built using Drupal.

When a user visits the homepage (https://scholars.umd.edu/) and scrolls down slowly(the issue magically vanishes when we quickly scroll down), the red band at the top seems to get stuck for a while and it is only after scrolling more and more that a user is able to scroll down finally.Please go to the website and scroll down on the home page and you will understand the issue.

I am attaching the relevant Javascript file where I think the issue might be present but I am newbie in JS so not really sure whats going on with the jQuery calls etc.

**Update:** *The issue only happens in Chrome and not in Firefox or IE. the chrome version I am using is Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit). Also, the issue happens when I use the mouse to scroll down or when i use the touchpad and scroll down slowly. If I click and drag the scroller on the right, the issue is not present.* 
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
 function stickymenu() {

```
var $this = this,
    $body = $("body"),
    header = $("#header"),
    headerContainer = header.parent(),
    menuAfterHeader = (typeof header.data('after-header') !== 'undefined'),
    headerHeight = header.height(),
    flatParentItems = $("#header.flat-menu ul.nav-main > li > a"),
    logoWrapper = header.find(".logo"),
    logo = header.find(".logo img"),
    logoWidth = logo.attr("width"),
    logoHeight = logo.attr("height"),
    logoPaddingTop = parseInt(logo.attr("data-sticky-padding") ? logo.attr("data-sticky-padding") : "28"),
    logoSmallWidth = parseInt(logo.attr("data-sticky-width") ? logo.attr("data-sticky-width") : "82"),
    logoSmallHeight = parseInt(logo.attr("data-sticky-height") ? logo.attr("data-sticky-height") : "40");

if(menuAfterHeader) {
    headerContainer.css("min-height", header.height());
}

$(window).afterResize(function() {
    headerContainer.css("min-height", header.height());
});

$this.checkStickyMenu = function() {

    if(!menuAfterHeader) {

        if($(window).scrollTop() > ((headerHeight - 15) - logoSmallHeight)) {

            $this.stickyMenuActivate();

        } else {

            $this.stickyMenuDeactivate();

        }

    } else {

        if($(window).scrollTop() > header.parent().offset().top) {

            header.addClass("fixed");

        } else {

            header.removeClass("fixed");

        }

    }

}

$this.stickyMenuActivate = function() {

    if($body.hasClass("sticky-menu-active"))
        return false;

    logo.stop(true, true);

    $body.addClass("sticky-menu-active").css("padding-top", headerHeight);
    flatParentItems.addClass("sticky-menu-active");

    logoWrapper.addClass("logo-sticky-active");

    logo.animate({
        width: logoSmallWidth,
        height: logoSmallHeight,
        top: logoPaddingTop + "px"
    }, 200, function() {});

}

$this.stickyMenuDeactivate = function() {

    if($body.hasClass("sticky-menu-active")) {

        $body.removeClass("sticky-menu-active").css("padding-top", 0);
        flatParentItems.removeClass("sticky-menu-active");

        logoWrapper.removeClass("logo-sticky-active");

        logo.animate({
            width: logoWidth,
            height: logoHeight,
            top: "0px"
        }, 200);

    }

}


$(window).on("scroll", function() {

    $this.checkStickyMenu();

});

$this.checkStickyMenu();


}

stickymenu();
```

});

Comment: Whoever has down-voted, would you please give a reason ? I would appreciate facts/rules rather than curiosity.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but you need to post code here, not just a link to a production site. When the question is answered you're going to fix the site, and then how will anyone be able to see what the problem was?

Comment: Interesting thing: it only happens when I used the scroll wheel, not when I drag the scroll bar.

Comment: Posting hundreds of lines of Javascript is also not appreciated.  Try to reduce your example to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can post here. It shouldn't be hard for you to narrow down the Javascript to just the part that handles scroll events.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue. I'm on Sierra, Chrome 55.0.

Comment: P.S I'm unable to reproduce the issue. I'm on Sierra, Chrome 55.0, Firefox 54.0.1 and Safari 10.1.1

Comment: I just checked and the issue is not reproducible on IE or Firefox. Its occuring only on Chrome. the version i have for chrome is Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @Barmar I tried looking around to find a specific snippet of code but cannot locate one point in the code where the issue is present. And as I said, I am not an expert in JS, so that is also a reason. There's a main umdheader variable and at many place in the js code, some jQuery code is applied  to that variable at multiple places in the code; also since most of this code is Drupal generated, i have not explicitly coded it. Would you recommend something else in this case so that i can get the -1 for the question removed and other people try to answer it ?

Comment: You're probably never going to get a good score for this question without significant work on your part. You need to narrow down what to look for, and post the relevant sections here. No one is going to do the debugging on the live site for you.

Comment: @Barmar I appreciate your comments. I am going to get in touch with a friend who has some FEE experience. I will update this post appropriately once I am able to figure out something specific. Having said that, I do see what you're saying.

Comment: @Barmar I have added the exact JS file responsible for the issue. Could you please remove the downvote and help me make this question reach the right people ?

Comment: I'm not a moderator, I can't remove downvotes from other people.

Comment: @Barmar I was just referring to yours, the one you had put in 2 months back, which seems to have been removed now, that's all I needed from you.

Comment: My comment 2 months ago starts with "Didn't downvote". Why do you think I downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

You could be seeing this due to the way Chrome is applying your wheel events. [Ben Nadel explain this in more detail.](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3535-chrome-browser-bug-scroll-wheel-randomly-stops-working-in-overflow-container.htm)

The solution to your problem most likely boils down to setting `overscroll-behavior: contain` on your `overflow: auto` container.